# Is there any utility which could merge two sorted array?

Tags: java

I am wondering if there are some utilities(library) to merge two sorted array in just 1 line.

Comment: Of course. Google Merge Sort. You'll find a lot of them. You do know requests for off-site resources are off-topic?

Comment: I know merge sort, but I just would like the merge sub function, any existing library to support?

Comment: This answers your question: `Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(array1), Arrays.stream(array2)).sorted(comparator).toArray(ArrayClass[]::new);`

Comment: @JacobG. I suspect that the time complexity of the method you suggested is O(n log(n)). It answers the question but seems to be doing a lot more work than is necessary.

Comment: @LakshayGarg I agree; I never said it was efficient ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`CollectionUtils.collate`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#collate-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-) from Apache Commons.

From the documentation:

> Merges two sorted Collections, a and b, into a single, sorted List
>   such that the natural ordering of the elements is retained. Uses the
>   standard O(n) merge algorithm for combining two sorted lists.

Here's an example

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;

public class MergeSortedArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer a[] = new Integer[]{2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
        Integer b[] = new Integer[]{1, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        List<Integer> merged = CollectionUtils.collate(asList(a), asList(b));
    }
}
```

The library also provides a few more useful overloads

```
// 1. discards duplicates
static <O extends Comparable<? super O>> List<O> collate(Iterable<? extends O> a, Iterable<? extends O> b, boolean includeDuplicates)
// 2. uses a custom comparator
static <O> List<O> collate(Iterable<? extends O> a, Iterable<? extends O> b, Comparator<? super O> c)
// 3. uses a custom comparator and discards duplicates
static <O> List<O> collate(Iterable<? extends O> a, Iterable<? extends O> b, Comparator<? super O> c, boolean includeDuplicates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't creating a simple merge function be better than adding a whole library for such a simple task?

You have array1(0,1,2,2,3,4)and array2(0,2,4,5) and a returnArray
Look at the first 2 values and pick the lowest, if theyre the same pick array1

Add that value to returnArray.

Keep removing that value from the picked array

Repeat process until merged

You can just increase an integer instead of removing for efficiency issues.

*Edit* Whoops, didnt realize you already knew merge sort

Comment: Correct, adding a library just for the sake of having this function is probably not such a good idea. However, a number of libraries like Google Guava and Apache Commons are almost always present in any java project of non-trivial size/complexity. In such cases, it is nice to have a well-tested library function which does the work for you.

Comment: Indeed. I often use both guava and commons in ny projects, cheers!